# Many to Many Relationship on OpportunityLineItem, and similar Junction Objects.

Tags: relationships, junction-object, data-model

I'm trying to add special characteristics that are not entirely products, so I thought, that the best way would be to make a many-many relationship between the Opportunity Line Products, Quote Products, and Order Items, to another "table" that contains all the possible characteristics, but I can't make the relationship between Opportunity Line Product, It doesn't allow me to make a reference to it from another object.

Could It be that I have a bad approach? or is there a way to do this or do it better?

The idea is
Opportunity Item (Standard) points to Opportunity(Standard), and Product(Standard)
And I want to have a table that is like
Features-OpItems that points to Opportunity Item and Features(Custome Object)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't create lookup relationships to certain types of objects. All of the Line Item objects fall in this category, as do others like Contact Roles and Partner Roles. They're just "lite" objects that lack full functionality in one or more ways. One possible workaround would be to make a custom object that steps in the middle, like "Item Feature Set"; it would be created by trigger for each line item created. From there, you could have your Item Feature object that links to the Item Feature Set object and the Feature object. You might end up having to write a component or Visualforce page if you want everything directly available on the Opportunity Line Item, etc, but realistically, it's the best you can do given the limitations of the platform.

Comment: I don't have salesforce open right now, but I saw, that you could do relations with Quote Line Items (I don't remember the name), and Order Items... The only restriction is to order Items... I found a way arround some stuff, by making a product features objects, that is referenced by opportunity Item, and that points to order and quote items, and, also it points to it self, so you can have a main feature, and the rest, of the features, the product item wont point to them, but they will point to the main feature so you can recover th relation Its workable, and enables you to do cool Componetns